# Function not getting called from jquery google apps Script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So i have a function which works fine when i run, as i  can see it output data to the logs, now i want to make it more ui friendly and call that function by clicking a button. I can't get the function to work from the ui what am i missing? please help. Here's my code.

```
function showDialog()
          {
            var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Show')
            .evaluate().setWidth(300).setHeight(400);
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, "Select a folder");
          }
    function generateFolderTree() {
      Logger.log("generateFolderTree called");
      try {


        var parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

        getChildFolders(parentFolder);

      } catch (e) {

        Logger.log(e.toString());

      }

    }


    function getChildFolders(parent) {

      var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

      while (childFolders.hasNext()) {

        var childFolder = childFolders.next();

        Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());

        var fold = childFolder.getName();
       }
    }




 Show.html

    <!-- USe a templated HTML printing scriphlet to import common stylesheet. -->
        <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Stylesheet").getContent(); ?>
        <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->

        <div>
        <div class = "block" id = "dialog-elements">
        <button class = "selectFolder" id = "selectFolder" >Select a Folder</button>
        </div>
        <!-- This block is going to be hidden until the user selects a folder -->
        <div class = "block" id = "hiddenAttrib">
        <p><label for = "SelectedFolder"> Selected Folder: </label></p>
        <p><label id = "foldername"> Folder Name: </label></p>
        <p><label id = "folderid"> Folder ID: </label></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "folderTable" id = "folderTable">
        <p><label class = "showStatus" id = "dialog-status">Status: </label></p>
        <table style = "width:100%" id = "source">
        <!--<tr>
           <td> <button>Awesome</button></td>
        </tr>-->


        </table>


        </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
        <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ShowJavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

jquery

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $("button").click(runMyFunction);
    });
    function runMyFunction(){

    //this.disabled = true;
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(generateFolderTree)
    .withFailureHandler(showError)
     $("#hiddenAttrib").hide();
        var counter = 4;
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<counter; i++){
          var row = $("<p><tr><td><button>This is a test</button></td></tr></p>");
          $("#source").append(row.html());
    }
    }

    function showError(error) {
        console.log(error);
        window.alert('An error has occurred, please try again.');
      }
    </script
```

>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 'jquery' script you are not calling the function.

The pattern to call it should be:

```
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(successCallback)
.withFailureHandler(errorCallback)
.appsscriptFunction()
```

So for your case it should be:

```
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(successCallback)
.withFailureHandler(showError)
.generateFolderTree()
```

The functions you use in `withSuccessHandler` and `withFailureHandler` are functions in the client side, the same you are doing with the function `showError` but you also need a function for when the call is successful.

You can see this in this [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it and got it to work. Much appreciated

Comment: i have stored the values being gen from the generateFolderTreess function in an array, now i need to pass the array values into jquey and append to the table as buttons. Any pointers as to how to do this?

Comment: Return that array in your generateFolderTreess function, but you will have to stringify it ( return JSON.stringify(array) ) . In the client call back function the returned value will come in the parameter of the function e.g. callBack(result){}  ... Then you will have to convert that string again into an array   ...  var newArray = JSON.parse(result.values)

Comment: can't get it to work, can you please show me an example